# How to remove underline text decoration for the link element?

Tags: html, css

Please see this [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/lolerine/2/edit?html,css,output). I would like to make `Project name` there as the link. It is shown with underline on `hover` by default. How can I remove it?

I've tried assigning a class `project-name`:

```
  a:hover, a:focus .project-name {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

But it affects other links also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a difference between this: `a:focus .project-name` and this: `a.project-name:focus`.

The first selects descendant elements of a focused `a` that have a class of `project-name`. The second selects an `a` that has a class of `project-name` and is focused.

All that to say, you need to do this:

```
a.project-name:hover, a.project-name:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
a.project-name:hover, a.project-name:focus {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  a.project-name:hover, a.project-name:focus{
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

Comment: Could you expound a little on how this will affect the OP's CSS?